# While importing a full package how to prevent the unwanted classes loaded? What are the important places GC has to be performed when using awt swing?

Tags: java, performance, swing, garbage-collection, awt

I'm doing programs via notepad (windows 7)importing the whole package makes the code simple, but the program looks quite weighing when i used verbose command. While compiling and running my java class, a lot of unwanted class files to the code has been loaded, is there any functionality in java so that it would prevent the unwanted loading of class files?

I knew there are IDE's but right now I'm feeling comfortable with notepad. So someone suggest if there is any functionality that avoids unwanted class loading to the program that I compile when a package is completely imported?

and When should be GC performed(specific areas whether when adding components/setting action events)?

Comment: Importing complete packages with the asterisk (*) does not automatically load all classes from the package. It is more like a shortcut to tell the compiler where to look for classes. Why not use an IDE like Eclipse? There exists very useful functionality to organize the imports.

Comment: @andreas - when running the java -verbose classname, my program is slowly loaded rather than java classname?? Why this difference?

Comment: ... Because it has more work to do?

Comment: It has nothing to do with importing whole packages vs. importing specific single classes. Most likely the difference is, as @ignis says, caused by to the overhead from the `-verbose` option. Especially when dumping to the console, this might have a big impact on runtime performance.

Answer (score 3):

Java is not a language carefully optimized for Notepad. Import statements are a prime case in point: without an IDE to manage them for you, you will experience day-to-day nuisances. You will finally succumb and admit that coding Java in Notepad is **not comfortable**.

Answering to your direct questions:

1. Import statements have nothing to do with class loading. They are there only to resolve the fully qualified name of a simple class name you use in your code. Classes are initialized strictly on demand, upon first usage and the way classes are loaded is implementation-specific, but typically it is lazy as well.
2. Garbage collection in Java is fully automatic and you should **never** execute it yourself. In fact, there is no mechanism to do so: `System.gc` is only a **hint** to the runtime.

Comment: what are the are the area that i should use GC, Whether while loading componenets are performing ActionEvents?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simple code snippet:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> l = new Vector<Object>();
        System.out.println("Hello World:" + l.size());
    }
}
```

To use `List` and `Vector`, you have to either

```
import java.util.*;
```

or

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
```

or, you could even add the package name to the class names in the code, and not use any import at all.

In either case, the output from `java -verbose` is exactly identical. Furthermore, in both cases, it lists 347 classes which are loaded for this simple code. The reason is that it does not only have to load `HelloWorld.class`, `java.util.List.class` and `java.util.Vector.class`, but also any dependant classes which are required by the Java runtime in order to execute your application (and, in this example, this includes `java.lang.System.class` and several classes from `java.io`, which are pulled in through the `System.out` reference).

So, there is no performance impact caused by importing complete packages. On a class file level, all classes are referenced through their fully qualified name, which includes the package name. This is independent from how the class was imported.